# Python - Получаю один и тот же ответ

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал по гайду код на Python, который показывает погоду и время в какой либо стране/городе
Ожидал я, что при написаний в input() Рудный, мне покажет погоду и время в моём городе, но что бы я не писал, я получаю один и тот же ответ
`<pyowm.weatherapi25.weather.Weather - reference_time=2021-02-04 09:17:01+00:00, status=clouds, detailed_status=overcast clouds>`

Я не знаю что можно попробовать чтобы исправить это, я лишь недавно начал изучать питон и пробую по гайдам научится pyowm
Хоть убирай ковычки в `observation = mgr.weather_at_place('place')`

Сам код:

```
import pyowm 

owm = pyowm.OWM('03f18')  # api key с сайта openweathermap.org

place = input("В каком городе/стране? Можно  на русском...: ") # Пользователь вводит город в импут

# Search for current weather in куда хош (куда хош)
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
observation = mgr.weather_at_place('place')

w = observation.weather
print(w)
```

Comment: `observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)` - передавайте place без кавычек, как переменную, а не как строку

Comment: А данные из этого объекта пробовали получать, например `w.temperature('celsius')` ?

Comment: Не нужно вандализировать свой вопрос

Comment: Вам нужно принять ответ зеленой галочкой и перестать портить вопрос.

Comment: @MajinSoil вы добиваетесь блокировки, или чего?

Answer (score 3):

Надо просто прочитать гайд чуть подальше и там все будет написано. В `w` у вас полученный объект. Чтобы получить его свойства, нужно обращаться к ним. Вот копипаста из описания модуля:

```
w = observation.weather

w.detailed_status         # 'clouds'
w.wind()                  # {'speed': 4.6, 'deg': 330}
w.humidity                # 87
w.temperature('celsius')  # {'temp_max': 10.5, 'temp': 9.7, 'temp_min': 9.0}
w.rain                    # {}
w.heat_index              # None
w.clouds                  # 75
```